# Angular- How to put $interval in use?

Tags: angularjs

I am taking date and time from the user input and

```
<input type="datetime-local" ng-model= "datetime" name="datetime" min="2016-01-01T00:00:00" max="2116-12-31T00:00:00" class="b" required/>
```

want to appear it in this div `<div ng-bind="x.todoTime| date : 'medium'" class="bb"></div>`
 but with the interval of 1000.How should I do it?

Js code:-

```
var app =angular.module('toDolist', []);
app.controller("toDoCtrl",function($scope, $interval) { 
$scope.todoWork = [];

    $scope.todoAdd = function() {      
$scope.todoWork.push({todoText:$scope.task,todoDesc:$scope.description,todoTime:$scope.datetime,todoPriority:$scope.priority,done:false});
            $scope.task ='';
            $scope.description ='';
            $scope.datetime ='';
            $scope.priority ='';
        };
    $interval(function(){
        $scope.datetime;;
      },1000);
```

Comment: What do you meant by **appear with the interval of 1000**?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you actually are trying to display, but it looks like you're trying to achieve something like this:

```
$interval(function() {
    $scope.x.todoTime = $scope.datetime;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you actually are trying to display in todo div, but I think you want to call a function after 1000 MS, You can call a function in interval, Like:

```
$interval(function() {
    $scope.yourFunction();//In this function you do calculation
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use $timeout in your controller.

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.datetime;
  },1000);
```

Comment: It will be called once only. @shreya is trying to call function at regular interval repeatedly.

Comment: how to call it repeatedly also I dont want static value, The user is putting the value and I want it to appear in another div with interval of 1000

Answer (score -1):

Just assign some value to the DateTime field.. It is working when i test with static value

```
$interval(function(){

 $scope.datetime="2017-01-01T00:00:00";

  },1000);
```

Comment: can you please tell me the reason for unliking the answer??

Comment: do anyone know the problem